# Replace a ID field with a combo box field

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have 2 SharePoint lists; Assets & Media.. Inside the Assets list I am storing the MediumID inside a number field.. now inside the Assets form i want to replace the MediumID with the combo box that contain the Media items to select from.. for both NEW Form, Displayform and EditForm.

So inside the Assets form I removed the MediumID number field >> and I added a combobox named "MediumCoboBox", with these values:

[image]

and inside the MediumID data card added the following Update property:

[image: thumbnail image 2 of blog post titled]

this is working for adding new Assets, but when editing or viewing the Assets inside the AssetForm the MediumCombobox will always be empty.

So what I need to define inside the `Default` property?

Comment: is this a single selection combo box? Try setting it to `LookUp(Media,ID=ThisItem.MediumID)`. Let me know if it works, else you will have to set `DefaultSelectedItems` property of combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If your combo box control is configured to have single selection only, set `DefaultSelectedItems` property of combo box control in Power Apps to:

```
LookUp(Media,ID=ThisItem.MediumID)
```

Where `ThisItem` is the context of record from `Assets` list and `MediumID` is the name of column in Assets list.